# Declare interest after declining recruiter

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

I have previously respectfully declined a recruiter who was interested on scheduling an interview with me for a team lead position. My reason is that I am currently happy with my job. What would be the best way or how do I approach the person again and tell him that I have changed my mind and I want to give it a go. Maybe go thru the interview and if that goes well, I wanna see what they have to offer for me.

Comment: Contact him again and say "hi, things changed"? What *exactly* is the problem?

Answer (score 10):

Assuming that not a great deal of time has passed say something like:

> Hi [recruiter], I've been thinking about that team lead role we were talking about on [date] and I've reconsidered. Would it still be possible for you to put me forward?

If it's a longer time frame then go with:

> Hi [recruiter], I've been thinking about that team lead role we were talking about on [date] and I've reconsidered. Would it still be possible for you to put me forward? I understand that this was some time ago and that the role may no longer be available but I'd like you to consider me for any similar roles that come up in the future

It *really* isn't any more complicated than that.

Comment: Nice and simple. It's good to not overthink things